# How to Change Bootstrap Tooltip text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried a lot of different answers from here on stackoverflow and around the internet but none have fixed it.

Here's what I have:

- http://jsbin.com/hehijuho/4/
- http://jsbin.com/hehijuho/4/watch?html,css,js,output

As you can see, it does successfully change the title of the button after clicking it but it doesn't change the tooltip text. Any help would be great because like I said, I've tried every other solution I've found on here & all the others I've found on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using fixTitle method of the bootstrap tooltip. Hope you don't mind using jQuery.
[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/xopiq/2/edit)

```
function fav(my_id, my_btn) {
    "use strict";
    var button = $('#' + my_btn);
    var icon = $('#' + my_id);
    if (icon.attr('class') === "glyphicon glyphicon-star yellow") {
        icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty');
        button.attr('data-original-title', 'Add to Favorites')
          .tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
    } else {
        icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-star yellow');
        button.attr('data-original-title', 'Remove from Favorites')
          .tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');

    }
}
```